# Grunt copying to location has full src path location appended, instead of just the dest property

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-copy

I am trying do the following:

```
FOLDERS.GRUNT = "js/grunt"

grunt.initConfig({
//copies from .tmp to final locations
    copy: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          dot: true,
          dest: FOLDERS.GRUNT,
          src: [
            FOLDERS.GRUNT + '/.tmp/*.js'

          ]
        }
        ]
      }
    },
```

I would expect the files to end up in **js/grunt** but for some reason ends up in **js/grunt/js/grunt/.tmp/myfile.js**

Also tried using **cwd:FOLDERS.GRUNT** but has the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

This approach will work without flattening the directory.

```
grunt.initConfig({
  copy: {
    dist: {
      files: [{
        cwd: FOLDERS.GRUNT + '/.tmp',
        expand: true,
        dest: FOLDERS.GRUNT,
        src: ['*.js']
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well answer is quite simple really:

use:

```
copy: {
  dist: {
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      dot: true,
      dest: FOLDERS.GRUNT,
      flatten: true,
      src: [
        FOLDERS.GRUNT + '/.tmp/*.js'

      ]
    }
    ]
  }
},
```